# Connect PHP to MySQL using Native Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, mysql, authentication

Can PHP applications connect to MySQL using Native Windows Authentication?

More context...

I'm setting up a PHP Web application (MediaWiki) on Windows and I would like to use the credentials of the Apache HTTPD service account (a Windows domain user) to connect to MySQL using Integrated Windows Authentication and avoiding the need to supply a password.

The commercial editions of MySQL includes a [Windows Native Windows authentication plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-authentication-plugin.html), which covers the server-side, but does PHP support connecting to MySQL using NWA?

UPDATE: Just found this: ["Connector/PHP 5.3: No, currently no plans to support WNA in PHP"](http://larsthalmann.blogspot.ca/2011/10/windows-native-authentication-for-mysql.html), which leads me to believe that this may not be possible.

Comment: Given that your webserver should be the least privileged process in your stack, there doesn't appear much to be gained by doing this.

Comment: There is much to be gained in managing a large enterprise system of systems where we need all services to be run under Windows domain user accounts where passwords must be changed regularly as per policy. Furthermore, we will eventually move to Windows Managed Service Accounts and get rid of passwords altogether.